# how to use magmi for importing in magento?

Tags: magento, import, bulk, magmi

I want to import simple products by magmi, installed already and the csv created with one sample product, magmi can read it but not inserting it, the csv is the default but with media_gallery column i don't know what to check for plugins and what configuration should i use, the categories not created so i checked (On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.3) and (Image attributes processor v1.0.25), is there any way i can know more details about the reason the importing not working like a error log ? and  simply how i can import via magmi ?

Comment: i think it is related to mapping, as i am using categories column but i can't find the csv at magmi/plugins/itemprocessors/genericmapper/mappings , no itemprocessors directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can get most of the information on [their website.](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki)

After that you can run magmi with the command from your magento root directory:

```
$ php magmi/magmi.cli.php -mode=xcreate -SKUF:matchfield=sku
```

All the configuration should be in /magmi/config. The logs you're gonna find in /magmi/state

That is the basic information you need to get started.

Comment: Thanks Madina it was reconfiguration by me and now it is working just perfect except of the image,small_image and thumbnail are get execute even after adding the + before i have to uncheck manyally .. trying to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Magmi v0.7.15b installation with magento 1.9.1.0 and ubuntu package 14.04

1. Copy magmi to your root directory and unzip it as(http://website.com/magmi)
2. Give permission 705 or 777 to this directory (sudo chmod 705 -R /var/www/html/magmi)
3. Browse to http://website.com/magmi/web/magmi.php
4. configure Global parameters as

   - host localhost
   - port 3306
   - version of magento 1.9.x
   - DB name yourDB name
   - Username Yourusername & password
   - Current profile Default
5. Data sources

   - CSV Datasource v1.3.1
   - CSV import mode local
   - CSV base directory var/import
   - CSV header at line Array
     and enter all option as per requirement and save profile
6. Restart apache2 sudo service apache2 restart
7. Refresh your magento admin panel

Comment: How can i import images for my multi store products, can i get csv header columns